# How to render the text in the editor of column of grid panel differently(ExtJs6.0.2)

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs, extjs6-classic

I have grid with a column that has an editor configured as text field.

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            itemId: 'gridPanel123',
            store: store,
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'cellediting',
                clicksToEdit: 1
            },
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'textfield'
                }
            }]
});
```

Say the column looks something like this,

[image]

Clearly the value of the column is ABCDE.
Now when the user clicks on the column, the editor mode pops up something like this :

[image]

Now my question is, is there any kind of renderer that would change the content of the editor based on the value of the column.

Considering my example, column value is "ABCDE", so the editor value is also coming as "ABCDE".

But what if I want to replace all 'A' in the column with 'Z' in the editor .So the editor value for me should have been 'ZBCDE'. How is this possible in extjs?

Comment: When closing the editor, do you need your action to be reverted? e.g. All Zs to become As again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting value in `beforeEdit` event in cell editing plugin.

```
cellediting: {
     listeners: {
          beforeEdit: function (editor, context) {
               context.value = context.value.replace("A", "Z");
          }
     }
}
```

To determine which column should be replaced just add check:

```
if(context.column.dataIndex == 'name'){
    context.value = context.value.replace("A", "Z");
}
```

To reverse replace try :

```
validateEdit: function (editor, context){
    context.record.set('name', context.value.replace("Z", "A"));
    context.record.commit();
}
```

Example on fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2thq.

Comment: That works very well. But could you also please tell me how to do the inverse. i.e what ever user puts on the editor, I want a different value to be reflected on the grid column value. Your help would be very much appriciated

Comment: And also your solution will be applied to all columns of the grid. What if I want this listener applied to only some of many of the grid columns